# Getting data from particular columns in a text file among other data using python and print on command prompt

Tags: python-2.7

Please help me in getting getting only DEST ADDR and NEXT HOP address columns among other data.

```
DEST ADDR           NEXT HOP          IFACE   SN    METRIC  QLEN    

c0:4a:00:cf:65:d4   c0:4a:00:cf:65:d4   wlan1     115615    23  0   

e8:de:27:77:7f:d9   e8:de:27:77:7f:d9   wlan1     626813    61  0   

e8:de:27:77:56:87   e8:de:27:77:56:87   wlan1     196910    1261    0   
e8:de:27:77:56:7e   e8:de:27:77:56:7e   wlan1     662029    46  0   

e8:de:27:77:6b:72   e8:de:27:77:7f:d9   wlan1   601792  198 0   

c0:4a:00:9a:6e:fa   c0:4a:00:9a:6e:fa   wlan1      6245 21  0   
root@wumesh-30:~# iw
Station c0:4a:00:cf:65:d4
inactive time:
expected throughput:
Station e8:de:27:77:7f:d9
inactive time:
expected throughput:
Station e8:de:27:77:6a:91
inactive time:
root@wumesh-30:~# iw
```

What I have tried:

```
with open("output.txt") as openfile:
    for line in openfile:
        for part in line.split():
            if "DEST" in part:
                print part+" ADDR",      "             NEXT HOP"
                for columns in ( raw.strip().split() for raw in openfile):  
                    if len(columns)>1 and part == "DEST":       
                       print columns[0], columns[1]
```

What I got:

```
DEST ADDR              NEXT HOP
c0:4a:00:cf:65:d4   c0:4a:00:cf:65:d4
e8:de:27:77:6a:91   e8:de:27:77:56:87
e8:de:27:77:7f:d9   e8:de:27:77:7f:d9
e8:de:27:77:56:87   e8:de:27:77:56:87
e8:de:27:77:7f:2b   e8:de:27:77:7f:d9
e8:de:27:77:56:7e   e8:de:27:77:56:7e
e8:de:27:77:6b:72   e8:de:27:77:7f:d9
c0:4a:00:9a:6e:fa   c0:4a:00:9a:6e:fa
root@wumesh-30:~# iw
Station c0:4a:00:cf:65:d4
inactive time:
expected throughput:
Station e8:de:27:77:7f:d9
inactive time:
expected throughput:
Station e8:de:27:77:6a:91
inactive time:
root@wumesh-30:~# iw
DEST ADDR
e8:de:27:77:6b:72   e8:de:27:77:6b:72
e8:de:27:77:56:7e   e8:de:27:77:56:7e
c0:4a:00:cf:65:d4   e8:de:27:77:6a:91
e8:de:27:77:7f:2b   e8:de:27:77:6a:91
e8:de:27:77:7f:d9   c0:4a:00:9a:6e:fa
e8:de:27:77:6a:91   e8:de:27:77:6a:91
c0:4a:00:9a:6e:fa   c0:4a:00:9a:6e:fa
e8:94:f6:67:c6:ce   e8:de:27:77:6a:91
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're consuming the totality of your file (`openfile`) in the inner loop.

Instead make a copy by forcing iteration once and for all through a `list`:

```
with open("output.txt") as openfile:
    lines = list(openfile)  # copy the file
    for line in lines:
        for part in line.split():
            if "DEST" in part:
                print part+" ADDR",      "             NEXT HOP"
                # now use lines instead of file handle
                for columns in ( raw.strip().split() for raw in lines):  
                    if len(columns)>1 and part == "DEST":       
                       print columns[0], columns[1]
```

that is, assuming that the rest of the code is correct which seems so, but that would need optimization. See you at code review for that.